# using if else with codeigniter return value

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I am using codeigniter framework for one of my inventory management systems.
I prefer using php due to its variable functionality which makes things easier.

So I am trying to get the username from session and then check the database for the level of the user and accordingly he should be able to view links in the navigation menu.

```
$this->db->select('level');
$this->db->where('name', $this->session->userdata('name'));
$query = $this->db->get('admin');

if ($query) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->level ;

}
}
```

This works fine and gets the level of the logged in user.
Now I want to use a if condition with this value, so I am using this -

```
if ($this->$row->level = '3') {

?>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="http://example.com/crm/emp_rep1.php">Employee Sales Report</a>
                        </li> 

<?php } ?>
```

But nothing seems to happen here, No error or any notice.

I have no clue what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: show us your controller and your model
$this->$row->level looks really wrong here  - but if you want an answer you have to give us your controller to see how you pass the model data to your view

Comment: post your controller and model as well

Comment: @sintakonte : thanks for your reply. My controller file is of 1044 lines. Not sure how do i show it here. Other then that if you see I am getting the user level in my first query. I want to use that value in the if statement.  I even tried using this - 
 $ulevel = $row->level ;
 
 if ($ulevel = '1'):
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($this->$row->level = '3') {

?>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="http://example.com/crm/emp_rep1.php">Employee Sales Report</a>
                        </li> 

<?php } ?>
```

you shouldn't use = operation for equal. should use == or === for equal. by that code you put 3 $this->$row->level and make it's value 3.

```
if ($this->$row->level == '3') {

?>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="http://example.com/crm/emp_rep1.php">Employee Sales Report</a>
                        </li> 

<?php } ?>
```